# Lost all login details after the death of administrator of a website hosted in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, password, password-recovery

My customer's administrator recently died and now my customer has no login data, neither for the backend of his content-management-system nor the administration system of his provider. He only has an FTP-Login left.

Via hostadvice.com I found out that his website is hosted on Google Cloud Platform.

Is there a way to retrieve the login data when both the login and the password are missing?

What can I do or what must my customer do to get the control of his webspace back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I recommend  you to remove your domain from the original post,
Then I think @massimo is right, the best option is to contact Google directly.

Please take a look at the following [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6335621?hl=en) to know more information about how to recover the control from your account.

According to this information If you can't contact your admin , you need to fill out the following form  [Google Admin console login issues form](https://support.google.com/a/contact/recovery_form).

Additionally, you can visit this URL [Can't sign in to your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/2402620) this link is to recover the Google account.

I hope this information is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You really should ask Google support; if you can provide proof that your customer is the real owner of the web site, they should be able to reset access credentials.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Can you give me a hint or a link, where I con find help? When I enter "google support", choose "google cloud" > "google cloud platform" I can enter a question that doesn't get me any further. I can click on "contact" > "not sure what my support package is" but then I have to login with this very login I do not have...